# Dynamic Menu population based on role and permission

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hope all doing well. In my java project i have to populate dynamic menu based on user role and permission. Could any one help me with code or tips to get the need.Thanks in advance.. I am using java, spring2.5,and mysql database....

Thanks...

Comment: Please expand a little bit on this. The values you want to use for the menu population, are a discrete number of values, retrieved from a db, dynamically calculated? there are several solutions to your question but you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Security. Like all other Spring modules, you would simply configure the framework declaratively using XML (for defining roles etc.) and so it's quite flexible.

Spring Security comes with its own tag library that you would then use to secure your HTML elements. For example, to make a menu item available for Admin roles only just wrap it in an appropriate  tag.

Access this website to see more: http://www.springsource.org/features/security